# Shell getting error after trying to use cut and echo command

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, cut

Good day.

In an attempt to make a script that reads a file line by line and gets the 6th field of said line delimited by ";" i get the following message:

```
/directory/file.txt: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
/directory/file.txt: line 1: `name;123456789;middlename;01/01/2017;9876543210;555555555555;product;;;'
```

The files.txt lines are like the following

```
name;123456789;middlename;01/01/2017;9876543210;555555555555;product;;;
```

the last ";" are there because the text file was copied from a excel file which was later converted to unix format of dos2unix. When i use the cut command out of the script i get what i want just fine but if i use it inside the loop below i get that error message:

```
#!/bin/bash

file = "/directory/file.txt"

for line in file;
do
    cut -d";" -f6 line
done
```

Why does this happen and how do i fix it?

Comment: You may want to change `cut -d";" -f6 line` to `echo $line | cut -d";" -f6`

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with your script. What are the exact commands you're running?

Comment: it is the very last command written in the question.

Comment: @JoeyZhang Im getting the same error

Comment: The last command in your question is `done`. What are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene i use cut inside the for loop

Comment: No, what commands are you typing into your shell to get that error?

Comment: i put that on a script and then i simply run it

Comment: No, what are the actual commands you are typing?

Comment: if i use  cut -d";" -f6 file.txt  i get the numbers just fine. if i use this inside that script which uses the for loop i get that error message. it is literally all i do man.

Comment: to run the script i just type sh script.sh

Comment: OK. What output do you get from `sh -x script.sh`?

Comment: This would happen with `file= "/directory/file.txt"` but I don't see why it's happening with your posted `file = "/directory/file.txt"`.  In any case, run it though [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) and fix the auto detectable issues first

Comment: @melpomene i get the following /directory/file.txt: line 2: 11995683475: command not found

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man That's impossible. Show me a screenshot.

Comment: @melpomene cant show a screen shot because theres a lot of work related stuff here. But i get a line of that for every line in the file

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Then `script.sh` is the same as `/directory/file.txt`.

Comment: yes it is, they are in the same directory

Comment: i guess it is far to say i`m doing something stupid here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively everything about your code is wrong.

1. Assignment statements do not take whitespace on either side of the `=`
2. `for` does not open a file and iterate over its contents
3. Parameters are expanded by using the `$` operator; otherwise, they are just literal strings.

A simple working example:

```
file="/directory/file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s' "$line" | cut -d";" -f6
done < "$file"
```

Once you are using the `while` loop correctly, you can use the `read` command to do the field-splitting for you; no need for `cut`:

```
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 frest; do
    echo "$f6"
done < "$file"
```

Using an array shortens it a bit, but makes your code non-POSIX compliant.

```
while IFS=";" read -ra f; do
    echo "${f[5]}"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: `cut -d";" -f6 "$file"`

Comment: I'm correcting the syntax and assuming the body of the loop is more complex than simply echoing the desired field; otherwise, yes, just using `cut` would suffice.

Comment: well, my plan was to get the number it echos, save it on a separate file and them use it  on a zgrep command to search that number in another directory and get everything it can about said number.